# Disable Daylight Saving Functionality

Tags: php, function, date, time, dst

I have googled and found nothing so I thought I would ask here I have code that will allow users to manually enable or disable daylight saving time. The question by default do not run daylight saving time as I have code that will automaticly add a extra hour if daylight saving is turned on via the user and taking an hour away if it is disabled.

Thanks!

Comment: Look under Related, over to the right >>> might be something there.

Comment: "Enable/disable" DST via timezone selection...

Comment: Why do you not just use the raw standard offset of a timezone in your code if you want to get rid of DST?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to reinvent the wheel. Just use PHP's built-in date functions!

For each user, store their preferred timezone in the database, as a string (or an id uniquely mapping to a set of strings). For example, "Europe/London" or "America/Montreal". See http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php for the full list. 
When you load the user's profile, load also his/her timezone, and use it accordingly every time you format a date (either use the DateTimeZone class while using DateTime's methods, or set it globally for the script with [date_default_timezone_set()](http://php.net/date_default_timezone_set) ).

In this way DST is enabled/disabled automatically for that specific region (remember that DST starts and ends in different days across the world, and many areas do not implement it). As an option, if the user doesn't want DST to be changed automatically, s/he could choose "generic" timezones, like "Etc/GMT", "Etc/GMT+2", etc (see http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php )

Comment: Just to clarify `Etc/GMT+-xx`, which is not same as `GMT+-xx`, but is the reverse of that, so `Etc/GMT+2` is `GMT-2`.